# Trying to find the no-dominated solutions of two arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to find the no-dominated values of two arrays in an optimization problem.

I've two arrays, `lost_bars_array` and `prices_array`. What I want to do is MINIMIZE the lost bars, and MAXIMIZE the price. I want to get a final array named `no_dominated` with the index  of the non-dominates values of both arrays. It's easy to understand. Let me explain this with an example.

We have the inital two arrays:
[image]

The theorical process is something like:

**1.** Get the first value
[image]

**2.** Get the second one (index #1) and see if its a better solution than the first one. This means we've to see if the second one has LESS lost bars and a BIGGER price. This is not the case, it has LESS bars, but also LESS price, so we can't say it's a better solution. We save it as a posible solution
[image]

**3.** Now comes the next one, index #2, this one improves the solution of index #1 because it has LESS lost brs and a BIGGER price. But it doesnt improve index #0 because it has LESS lost bars but also LESS price. So we save index #0 and index #2 as possible solutions.
[image]

**4.** Index #3, and #4, has MORE lost bars and LESS price, so just reject them as possible solutions.

**5.** Finally, index #5, has LESS lost bars and MORE price than index #0, so, solution of index #0 is rejected, and the final no-dominated values will be the ones of index #2 and index #5.
[image]

This is what I've tried so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int lost_bars_array[] = {15, 10,  8, 15, 17,  9};
    int prices_array[]    = {35, 25, 30, 10, 15, 36};
    int no_dominated[6];
    int cont              = 6;

    for (int actual_pos = 0; actual_pos < cont; actual_pos++)
    { 
        if (actual_pos == 0)
        {
            no_dominated[actual_pos] = actual_pos; 
        } 
        else
        {
            // Here's where I've the problems, I dont know how to handle the arrays
            for (int p = 0; p < actual_pos; p++)
            {
                if (lost_bars_array[p] > lost_bars_array[p + 1] && 
                    prices_array[p] < prices_array[p + 1])
                {
                    no_dominated[p] = p;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe non-dominated solutions index are: %d");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", no_dominated[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The code should output the index `2 5` as solution.
I hope I explained the problem correctly. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `The problem should output 2 5 as solution.` This makes the question appear as an exercise to the reader.  Consider rephrasing.

Comment: What don't you know about handling the arrays?

Comment: Assuming that `no_dominated` contains the indices you want to save from your example, you'll need a separate counter for `no_dominated` (not p), that increases only when a possible solution is found (in your example, it would never go above 2 (0-based), since you have at most 3 indices saved. Then the inner loop only needs to loop through those indices.

Answer (score 1):

The program below gets what you want, but I've only tested it for your specific case; it may very well fail in case there is only one dominated solution, or in a few other special cases. But you may be able to work from this.

Two notes:

- you forgot to include the potential solutions; the boolean `&&` will only save solutions that are guaranteed to be better
- the last double loop is a bit of a hack; hashes would be easier (the solution index would be the hash), but I think that requires c++ or an extra library.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int lost_bars_array[] = {15,10,8,15,17,9};
    int prices_array[] = {35,25,30,10,15,36};
    int no_dominated[6];
    int cont = 6;
    int ndom = 0;

    no_dominated[ndom] = 0;
    ndom++;
    for (int actual_pos = 1; actual_pos < cont; actual_pos++) { 
        int ntmp = ndom;
        for(int p = 0; p < ntmp; p++) {
            if (lost_bars_array[no_dominated[p]] > lost_bars_array[actual_pos] && 
                prices_array[no_dominated[p]] < prices_array[actual_pos]) {
                // Replace with a better solution
                no_dominated[p] = actual_pos;
        } else if (lost_bars_array[no_dominated[p]] > lost_bars_array[actual_pos] ||
               prices_array[no_dominated[p]] < prices_array[actual_pos]) {
                // Save as potential solution
                no_dominated[ndom] = actual_pos;
                ndom++;
            }
        }
    }
    // Remove double solutions
    for (int i = 0; i < ndom; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < ndom; j++) {
            if (no_dominated[i] == no_dominated[j]) {
                ndom--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe non-dominated solutions index are:");
    for(int i = 0; i < ndom; i++)
        printf(" %d ", no_dominated[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep. It seems this fails if I change the `lost_bars_array`and `prices_array`. `int lost_bars_array[10] = {11, 17, 13, 11, 12, 16, 15, 20, 18, 17};` and `float prices_array[10] = {11756.30, 11956.70,  12232.30, 12184.70, 12184.70, 11756.30, 11565.90, 11565.90, 11470.70, 11470.70};`

Answer (score 1):

If you have n metrics to compare your data on (in your implementation n = 2 arrays with data to maximize/minimize), you can have at most n (2) non-dominated elements.

Hence you can just find the max/min element and index in each array and those will be your solution (if two indexes are the same, only add one of them).

You do not have to worry about domination at all and `no_dominated` does not have to have the size of your input. It's size will be between 1 and your number of metrics/datat arrays (in the example case, 1 or 2)